# ubuntu upgrade problem with py3compile not found

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

Ubuntu: 18.04

When I tried to do  `sudo apt-get upgrade` it gives me this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libpython3.7-minimal libpython3.7-stdlib
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up python3-software-properties (0.96.24.32.7) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-software-properties.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-software-properties.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-software-properties (--configure):
 installed python3-software-properties package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-software-properties
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

But suggested commend `sudo apt autoremove` also shows error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED
  libpython3.7-minimal libpython3.7-stdlib
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 2 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 12.1 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 178285 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libpython3.7-stdlib:amd64 (3.7.1-1~18.04) ...
Removing libpython3.7-minimal:amd64 (3.7.1-1~18.04) ...
Setting up python3-software-properties (0.96.24.32.7) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-software-properties.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-software-properties.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-software-properties (--configure):
 installed python3-software-properties package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-software-properties
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So it looks like there is some problem with py3compile which is not found. 
I try `sudo apt-get  -f install` which ends with:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up python3-software-properties (0.96.24.32.7) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-software-properties.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-software-properties.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-software-properties (--configure):
 installed python3-software-properties package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-software-properties
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The same kind of py3compile: not found error shows when i try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-minimal`

I'm new with ubuntu so I will be glad for some help with that.

Comment: It may be worth trying to remove packages one by one, for example like this: `sudo apt remove libpython3.7-minimal`

Answer (score 21):

[dpkg error: pycompile: not found - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30962402/)

**This answer helped me, hope it resolves someones problem.**

Reconfigure all unpacked, but unconfigured packages by:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

If the above won't help, try reinstalling `python3-minimal` package by:

```
sudo apt install -f --reinstall python3-minimal
```

Alternatively, run:

```
apt-get download python3-minimal
sudo dpkg -i *python3*.deb
sudo apt install -f
```

Or download the .deb file from kernel.org and install from the file by:

```
sudo dpkg -i python3-minimal_*.deb
```

Comment: Please include essential parts here.

Comment: This did not help, I still get the same errors. Please include more info.

Answer (score 4):

I got the problem of `py3compile not found` in Ubuntu 20.04.1 while installing `python3-pip`. I reinstalled `python3-minimal` as suggested by the answer and then again tried to installed `python3-pip` and it worked !

```
sudo apt install -f --reinstall python3-minimal

sudo apt install -f --reinstall python3-pip
```

Hope this helps someone in future !

Answer (score -4):

In my case i was upgrading Ubuntu 16. My solution was to set the default /usr/bin/python back to python2 as python3 did not have all dependencies needed.

```
rm /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3
ln -sf /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: This technique is perilous, particularly on multi-user systems, and should be applied with caution.

Comment: Yes, this is only an exception for the Ubuntu 16 Upgrade, no usual method! The links will be corrected within the upgrade.

Comment: Many modern applications depend on Python3 syntax. **DO NOT USE THIS METHOD** on 18.04 or above! This will throw more and more syntax errors.