# Ubuntu 20.04 + recent software update + terminal, software updates, software updater not working

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, 20.04, update-manager, python3

I am on dual boot with Windows 10.

I initially had Ubuntu 18.04 and updated to Ubuntu 20.04 last month. I usually run the software updater from time to time.

Last week, I ran the software updater and it updated and some ubuntu base files along with some software. It asked for a reboot after and so rebooted.

I tried some responses already in askubuntu and few other sites but none worked. Anyway, here is the problem.

Today, I see that software-updater, terminal are not working.

I tried the following already:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

It gave the following error:

```
sh 1: /usr/lib/cnf-update-db: not found
    Reading package lists... Done
    E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
    E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Then following some other posts, I tried checking for python and all I see is python2.7 is the only one present. I know that python3 was installed when it was upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 but after the last week's update, I am not sure how it is gone. Anyway, I tried to install the python3-minimal using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-minimal
```

and this did not work giving the errors saying unmet dependencies for python3-samba and python3-uno and suggested to use the following command

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

This also gave the following error:

```
Error encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/python3-distupgrade_1%3a20.04.19_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/python3-samba_2%3a4.11.6+dfsg_0ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/python3-uno_1%3a6.4.3_0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

In relation to this above error, it complains about `py3clean` and `py3compile` not found.

At this point, I am not sure how to fix this.

Can someone please help fixing this.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried using synaptic to correct broken packages ?

Comment: No, I did not. I have not tried it yet and so I shall explore. Good to know, Thanks @GiorgosSaridakis

Comment: I tried the answer for that question but they didn't work as is. It looked like a catch-22. So I had to install those manually by downloading the debian package and mentioned in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I kept trying while waiting for an answer and came across this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131816/ubuntu-upgrade-problem-with-py3compile-not-found) and the answer suggested to try installing the python3-minimal again. However, the individual commands failed in my case.

So, I tried the alternative route of downloading the python3-minimal*.deb to install it manually. I tried the following commands initially from my home dir initially and it gave permission error that _APT does not access to write in this directory. However, I changed to /tmp and executed the following and it installed python3-minimal. Now, I can see the software updater and gnome-terminal working fine again.

```
apt-get download python3-minimal
sudo dpkg -i *python3*.deb
sudo apt install -f
```