# Ubuntu 20.04 /var/lib/dpkg/info/software-properties-common.postinst: 6: py3compile: not found

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

When I try to upgrade by running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I get an error and the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree  
     
Reading state information... Done

Calculating upgrade... Done

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

3 not fully installed or removed.

After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.

Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y

Setting up software-properties-common (0.99.9.8) ...

/var/lib/dpkg/info/software-properties-common.postinst: 6:
py3compile: not found

dpkg: error processing package software-properties-common (--configure):

 installed software-properties-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Setting up python3-minimal (3.8.2-0ubuntu2) ...

/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-minimal.postinst: 5: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-minimal (--configure):
 installed python3-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of software-properties-gtk:
 software-properties-gtk depends on software-properties-common; however:
  Package software-properties-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package software-properties-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 software-properties-common
 python3-minimal
 software-properties-gtk
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The output of `which python python3` is:

```
/usr/bin/python
```

The output of `ls -l /usr/bin/python*` is:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Apr 15  2020 /usr/bin/python -> python2

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Mar 13  2020 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3674216 Mar  8  2021 /usr/bin/python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Jul  1 10:56 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.8

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Mar 15 17:52 /usr/bin/python3.8-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.8-config

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Mar 13  2020 /usr/bin/python3-config -> python3.8-config
```

The output of `sudo apt install python-is-python3` is:

```
Package python-is-python3 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source However the following packages replace it: python-is-python2
E: Package 'python-is-python3' has no installation candidate
```

I then followed the steps to revert to original repositories in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1305148) and ran again `sudo apt install python-is-python3` Which gave the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree    
   
Reading state information... Done

The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:

  libpython2-stdlib libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib linux-headers-5.13.0-48-generic linux-hwe-5.13-headers-5.13.0-48 linux-image-5.13.0-48-generic linux-modules-5.13.0-48-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-48-generic python2 python2-minimal python2.7 python2.7-minimal

Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ubuntu-advantage-tools
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  python-is-python2
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-is-python3

The following packages will be upgraded:
  ubuntu-advantage-tools

1 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

4 not fully installed or removed.

Need to get 879 kB of archives.

After this operation, 21.5 kB of additional disk space will be used.

Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y

Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-advantage-tools amd64 27.9~20.04.1 [876 kB]

Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu foca
l/main amd64 python-is-python3 all 3.8.2-4 [2,364 B]

Fetched 879 kB in 2s (361 kB/s)       
        
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-commandnotfound' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'apturl-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 220697 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ubuntu-advantage-tools_27.9~20.04.1_amd64.deb ...

/var/lib/dpkg/info/ubuntu-advantage-tools.prerm: 48: py3clean: not found...................................................................................................................................................] 
dpkg: warning: old ubuntu-advantage-tools package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Failed to stop ubuntu-advantage.service: Unit ubuntu-advantage.service not loaded.
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 48: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ubuntu-advantage-tools_27.9~20.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new ubuntu-advantage-tools package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/ubuntu-advantage-tools.postinst: 451: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed ubuntu-advantage-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/ubuntu-advantage-tools_27.9~20.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
prajesh@revyz-113:~$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ubuntu-advantage-tools
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-headers-5.13.0-48-generic linux-hwe-5.13-headers-5.13.0-48 linux-image-5.13.0-48-generic linux-modules-5.13.0-48-generic linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-48-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  ubuntu-advantage-tools
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 5 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/876 kB of archives.
After this operation, 508 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-commandnotfound' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'apturl-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 220697 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ubuntu-advantage-tools_27.9~20.04.1_amd64.deb ...

/var/lib/dpkg/info/ubuntu-advantage-tools.prerm: 48: py3clean: not found...................................................................................................................................................] 
dpkg: warning: old ubuntu-advantage-tools package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Failed to stop ubuntu-advantage.service: Unit ubuntu-advantage.service not loaded.
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 48: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ubuntu-advantage-tools_27.9~20.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new ubuntu-advantage-tools package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/ubuntu-advantage-tools.postinst: 451: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed ubuntu-advantage-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/ubuntu-advantage-tools_27.9~20.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137451/discussion-on-question-by-prajesh-sortee-ubuntu-20-04-var-lib-dpkg-info-softwar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some **really serious issues** with your current installation:

- The errors in the output of the `apt-get upgrade` commands are a result of a broken python install on your system ... You did something with your default python3 installation that rendered it nonfunctional.
- A symlink to `python3.8` is present in `/usr/bin` but the binary itself i.e. `/usr/bin/python3.8` is missing(*probably deleted the binary or even removed `python3.8` altogether*).
- The errors in the output of the `apt install python-is-python3` command suggest you have altered your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and added mixed sources from different releases/versions which is totally not recommended and should be avoided.

Although you can easily fix your sources list following the steps in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1305148/968501), `Python3` installation appears to be severely damaged on your system ... and although an advanced user might be able to fix it(*even then the process is lengthy and error prone*), an average user can't ... `python3` is vital for Ubuntu 20.04 and almost nothing can properly run without it ... Please see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1321433/968501) for detailed information.

A fresh install is the easiest right decision in your case ... I suggest you  **back up your data** then fresh install Ubuntu and don't mess with python again.

Comment: True. I will try to fresh install ubuntu and never ever try to mes with default python. Thanks @Raffa

Comment: Freshly installed ubuntu 20.04 thanks @Raffa for your help.

Comment: @prajeshsortee You are most welcome … It’s my pleasure to help.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure I was in the very same predicament, but the following command (found in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131816/ubuntu-upgrade-problem-with-py3compile-not-found)) simply fixed my `py3compile: not found` error:

```
sudo apt install -f --reinstall python3-minimal
```